# checking what check boxes are checked in given check boxes

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have 3 check boxes and i need to check what is the combination of check boxes that are checked

```
  <asp:CheckBox ID="chkCESUSA" runat="server" Text="CES USA" /><br /> 
  <asp:CheckBox ID="chkUSA" runat="server" Text="USA" /><br />  
  <asp:CheckBox ID="chkOther" runat="server" Text="Other" />
```

I want all the values of check-boxes that are checked (ex : if he selects only 1 then i should get that 1 value and if he selects 2 i need to get both of them and so on )
i can write that by using if conditions that would be a long code like more than 10 combinations so i would like to know whether there is any easier way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
var checkboxes = [];
$('input:checkbox:checked').each(function() {
    checkboxes.push($(this).val());
});
```

Comment: It will work but also i wanna show that checkboxes are not checked if they arent checked so   var vals = [];
//            $('input[type="CheckBox"]').each(function () {
//                vals.push($(this).val());
//                alert(vals);
//            });  i have made a slight improvisation of ur's as per my requirement Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [checked selector](http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector) along with [map()](http://api.jquery.com/map) to get an array of checked vlaues

```
var checked = $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').map(function(){
    return this.value
}).get()
```

Note: you can improve the checkbox selector using a name or class selector

Answer (score 2):

Use CheckBoxList, and put your options in the listItem.

Answer (score 1):

To make sure you will get values only of those checkboxes, you could add class to them and then use [`:checked`](http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/) to get all checked checkboxes of this class. After that you can loop through the array of elements you got with this selector. Check [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uL8ab/).

```
$("input.specific:checked").each(function( index ) {
   alert($(this).val());
});
```